# Dual national (France-Philippines) travelling to a third country (Morocco, with previous travel history)

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, morocco, 90-180-visa-rules

Been reading the threads here for a while and this is the first time I am posting.

I would like to ask for your help in finding an answer to my question:

I am Philippine-born and a dual citizen of both the Philippines and France.

I would like to travel to Morocco once again, where I have previously traveled as a Philippine citizen prior to getting my French passport (Philippine passport holders get 90-days visa free).

My question is this:

I know that I have to exit and re-enter France using my French passport (I know this thanks to this forum), but:

- Can I or should I use my Philippine passport upon entering Morocco (given my previous travel history to the country as a Philippine citizen)?
- Were I to use my French passport to enter Morocco (it's also 90-days visa free), would the Moroccan authorities question me on this?

All my details - first and last names, date and place of birth - are exactly the same on both passports.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use whichever option you prefer. It is not illegal. Nobody knows if they will question you, if they do you explain.

Comment: @Newton: Thanks for the comment. I am aware that my question is related to that post (hence my statement that I knew about travelling with two passports thanks to this forum), but my question really was whether I could/should use the passport from my original nationality (Philippines) since I had already traveled to Morocco using a Philippine passport before.

Comment: That entirely depends on you. Use whichever you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks @Newton for the reply. Yeah, I just wasn't sure from the link you posted  if it applied to someone traveling to a country C (where s/he already has travel history using country A's passport but wants to go there using country B's passport) :)